# Can retracted flags not be viewed in the mod flag count?

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags, moderator-tools

Whenever a user raises a flag and then retracts it, this is still shown in the mod dashboard with a handling time of 0 minutes:

> [image]

The flag wasn't really 'handled' so this gives a misrepresentation of the flags handled:

- It should not be included in this count
- It should have a separate count, something like:

> `0` flag, average handling time 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes, `1` retracted flag

Comment: Sounds more like a bug, but leaving the feature request tag as well just in case. :)

Comment: The page pre-dates the existence of retracting flags, so it wasn't something to take into consideration at the time and these dashboards haven't really been touched in a while. We've been working on improving mod tools so if we look at this page, we may be able to fix this in the future.